# How to generate a start_no and end_no of 1000 split from a table where in it contains numbers from 944900000 to 944999999 using oracle sql

Tags: oracle

The table contains numbers from 944900000 to 944999999 and i want to split these numbers into ranges of 1000 each like

- 944900000 to 944900999 -- 1000
- 944901000 to 944901999 -- 1000
- ..
- ..
- 944999000 to 944999999 -- 1000

is there any way to generate this through oracle SQL not with PL/SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` to number all records according to increasing number value.  Then, compute a `DENSE_RANK` using the "group" of increments of 1000 to which each record belongs.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY col) rn
    FROM yourTable t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FLOOR(rn / 1000)) dr
    FROM cte t
)

SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE dr = 2;   -- e.g. for 2nd partition of 1000 records
```

Comment: Used ceil instead of floor for geeting 1000 split and select max(col), min(col),count(*),dr from cte2 group by dr order by 1

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this.

```sql
--Your data
CREATE TABLE your_table(your_column) AS
SELECT 944900000 + LEVEL - 1
FROM dual
CONNECT BY 944900000 + LEVEL < 944999999 + 2
;

--from 944900000 to 944999999
WITH cte AS (
SELECT your_column, CASE WHEN MOD(your_column, 1000) = 0 THEN your_column END start_range
FROM your_table
)
SELECT start_range, end_range
FROM (
  SELECT start_range, CASE WHEN start_range IS NOT NULL THEN LEAD(your_column, 999)OVER(ORDER BY your_column) END end_range
  FROM cte
)T
WHERE end_range IS NOT NULL /*because of the last execution of lead function in the inline view t*/
GROUP BY start_range, end_range
ORDER BY 1, 2
;
```

Comment: Glad to see I could help